# Shattering The World- Energy Output?

Tags: internal-consistency, magic

I have a question because I'm interested in using a similar feat of monstrous strength for a character I'm developing. What can I say, curiosity killed the cat- let's say that a being trapped beneath the surface of the crust of a building of roughly the same shape and make of Earth broke through the crust and caused worldwide problems- things like Earthquakes due to plate shifting and whatnot. What would the actual energy be? Should be noted that magic does exist, if that helps.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Can you explain what you want an energy calculation for?

Comment: Shattering multiple country-sized tectonic plates by a burst of movement into the crust of a planet.

Comment: This page may be your new best friend: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(energy)

Comment: «the surface of the crust of a building of roughly the same shape and make of Earth»  huh?

Comment: "similar feat" Similar to what? "cat" What does a cat have to do with this? "crust of a building" Buildings don't have crusts. "magic does exist" I don't think that helps with anything... if anything it makes it less clear since you didn't explain the magic system. "reality-check" and "magic" tags are mutually exclusive. Sorry... for all these reasons, close as Unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as a lower bound, the Chicxulub impact (associated with the extinction of the dinosaurs) is often quoted at roughly 100 teratons of TNT equivalent (~4 x 10^23 joules), and while it made a crater c. 180 km wide, the North American Plate remained intact.

As an upper bound, the gravitational binding energy of the Earth is on the order of 2 x 10^32 joules / 5 x 10^22 tons of TNT. That's what it would take to literally blow the planet apart, Death Star style - all the pieces going to escape velocity so the debris wouldn't recoalesce into a planet.

Comment: So... somewhere in between an unimaginable amount and an infeasible amount then? But seriously, I think you're on the money with exceeding the gravitational binding energy of the planet, I mean, how else is it going to get "shattered?"